# cmd-line XCTests pass, even though test should fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcodebuild, xctest

Running XCTest-based tests from the cmd-line causes the tests to silently pass, even when a test fails when run via the IDE.

- Added a new XCTest-based test target to an iOS App.
- Ran tests with the following command:

> xcodebuild clean test -workspace VoucherBlaster.xcworkspace -scheme VoucherBlaster -configuration Debug -destination OS=7.1,name=iPad

- xcodebuild reported tests as passing, even though the example test failed.
- Used SenTest instead and the build reported failed tests, as expected.

**Questions:**

- Is this a common/known issue? (If it is I'd normally be surprised that the problem made it all the way into Xcode5.1 GA, but it wouldn't be the first time :-/ )
- Is there a work-around?

Comment: How do You recognize that tests silently pass? What is the exit code of the command?

Comment: @opal 'build successful' console out, plus success exit code.

Comment: Hmm.. It seems that `xcodebuild` is really useful tool. However this is really strange case. We invoke command line tests and the result is reliable. Why You invoke tests from command line? Maybe try `xctool`?

Comment: Why from cmd-line? For automated regression testing /CI, etc. I use a wrapper script: https://github.com/jasperblues/xcode-gradle . . Not a bad suggestion to try xctool

Comment: For CI we use apphance flow. `xcpretty` also nice tool. No idea how to help You unfortunately unless You give me access to the project - I know it may be impossible. For a long work with `xcodebuild` I've learnt that almost every case is different :/

Comment: I've noticed this silent failures with unhandled exceptions in a unit test. I don't know how to work around this and I think it deserves a bug to be filed against Apple.